# Battery for a 24 V, 200W or 250W DC motor

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, electric-machine

I am trying to build an electric scooter and have decided on either a 200 or a 250 W DC motor. However, I’m struggling to choose a battery that would be sufficient for these motors.

I want the scooter to continuously run for 30 mins to 1 hour. With the 1 hour assumption and an estimated motor efficiency of 70% I calculated that I would need a 12 Ah battery. I’m not sure if 70% is an adequate estimation, and I don’t know what my c value should be. I also saw many calculations from stall current online, saying that the battery need to be able to discharge at stall current rates. How relevant is that for the motor I’m using?

Comment: Well, what's the stall current of your motor?

Comment: Regenerative braking makes a difference. Also how many times you stop start or speed-up and slow down makes a big difference. Mass of the scooter plus one person is a biggy. Time it takes to accelerate to full-speed is also a biggy. In other words, you need to develop a typical usage profile to estimate battery size.

Comment: `How relevant is [stall current from battery] for the motor I’m using?` In revision 1 of your question, all you disclose about your motor type is "DC". If that does *not* include a controller, your motor *will* draw this current when accelerating from stand-still, and you don't want your battery damaged. Tell more about your motor: Edit your question.

Comment: Have you looked at scooter kits?

Comment: @Andyaka DC motor, regen isn't going to happen. It's hard. EVs that have regen use AC motors.

Answer (score 2):

Worst case 250 W, 1 hour:

$$
1h\times\frac{250 W}{24 V} = 10.417 Ah 
$$
At 70% efficency
$$
\frac{10.417 Ah}{0.7} = 14.881 Ah
$$

Your battery is going to need to supply that plus have some extra capacity so it's not totally drained at the end. Rule of thumb for lead-acid batteries is to not drain them below 50%, preferably not below 70%. If you're using something other than lead-acid you'll have to check the requirements for the type you have.

Using this [battery size calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/battery-size) and using 357 W to account for the efficiency gives us minimum size 48 Ah for 50% drain, 80 Ah for 30% drain.

This is the battery requirement to run the motor continuously. You'll also have to account for surge currents on start-up and stall, the battery will need to be rated to handle whatever those are, and the motor will probably not be running full tilt the entire time, so that reduces the requirements a bit. Bottom line is you can't just get a battery rated for the total power used, you need to size it to manage the amount the battery gets drained.